# CSS !important and inline style being overwritten

Tags: html, css, css-specificity, bulma

I am using Bulma to create a website and I have been having a weird issue with the *Tabs* component when being used in a *Hero* component. Tabs has a `margin-bottom` of *1.5rem* by default. However, this is not something that I desire and I want to remove this. I tried using `!important`, used an id and also used inline styles to try to override this style but none of them have worked. Any help in this regard would be appreciated. I have attached the HTML and CSS rules along with this post. I have even tried using `!important` along with the inline style but none of it works. 
I have also , unticking the margin-bottom
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please post the code in your question and provide a jsfiddle/plnkr showcasing the issue.

Comment: They are in the screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try **margin-bottom: 0** instead of margin-bottom: none. Because none is not a valid value for margin.

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted, it's the correct answer

Comment: Oh god, that was such a newbie mistake. Thanks -_-

Answer (score 0):

There is two ways to approach it, either `margin-bottom: 0` or `margin-bottom: initial` which by default is 0 in CSS. The correct way would be initial but either one should be fine